# No HDMI output decteded

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and trying to connect to my TV using the HDMI port on my computer. But nothing happens when I plug it in, and clicking on `Detect Displays` in the display settings does nothing.

How do I get it to detect HDMI ?

```
xrandr:
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767

LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm

1366x768       59.9*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: Is the TV compatible with computers? Also, try connecting it, rebooting, and running updates - `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: Which device you are running Ubuntu? Can you put the output of `lspci` into this question?

Comment: I have this intermittently, no idea why. Today my HDMI connection was "disconnected" and I got a new idea. I put a VGA cable into the monitor, and used VGA-> HDMI adapter to plug into the laptop. Viola, like magic, the monitor is found.  The display seems a little darker, otherwise adequate. Before that, I was suspecting the HDMI hardware jack in the laptop had a short circuit. Hardware seems OK, so problem seems in kernel. I just updated to  4.10.0-22-generic.